# Unlocked boot loader Moto G (4th Generation) - Amazon Prime Exclusive

Tags: bootloader-lock, motorola-moto-g-4g

Does the [Amazon Prime exclusive Moto G4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EZC9WC0) have an unlocked boot loader? This phone is $150. Is VoLTE. And, has Band 12. Can I buy it and put an AOSP on it and get around the Amazon adds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [No](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/87215)

The bootloader on the G4 Amazon Prime Exclusive is locked and can not be unlocked.

[image]